# How to calculate new speed using newtons second law based on previous speed

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, simulations, speed

I am creating a train simulator game, and I want to calculate the new speed based on previous speed.
I know i can calculate speed in my game with 
speed=(f/m)*frames elapsed*seconds per frame
But If the force changes because e.g. air drag force, then things go all wrong, and if i suddently get frame drops, everything goes wrong too.
So how would i calculate new speed based on what the speed was in the previous frame?(time between frames can be different)

Thanks

Comment: This question will likely be closed rather than fully answered unless you ask it much more clearly, show what you have tried so far, and make sure that your question is specifically about physics rather than game design.  That said, I think you will end up multiplying an acceleration by a time elapsed to get a change in velocity for each frame.

Comment: I did show what I currently have, but i have no idea how i could do what i want now. How could I improve my question?

Comment: Outside of the physics, I'd recommend taking some time to separate rendering and physics code. If they're tied together, expensive calculations can hurt framerate and fast framerates can make the physics simulations get weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the time interval, the average net force pushing the train forward during that time interval and the mass of the train, then:

$v_{new}={F_{net}\over m}\Delta t+v_{prev}$

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are lazily written and unresearched until the poster has improved the quality of the question.  See John Rennie's answer on this page for more thoughts about lazy questions: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/what-does-everyone-mean-by-insufficient-research-effort

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you maybe explain what t stands for?

Comment: ....and this is why we don't answer questions before the poster has put in some research effort...

Comment: @DuncanHarris , do you maybe know the answer?

Comment: Daniel named all of the variables in that equation in the line preceding the equation.  Just match the letters to his variable descriptions.  m=mass, f=force ... etc  Please take a moment to read and think before asking.